# sending email from gmail using xampp

Tags: php

I already watch and read all videos and the questions related to the problem "how to send **email** in **php** from **gmail** using **XAMPP**?? " . It run but the execution in **SENDMAIL.ini**  is not working well

[img Problem #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uiKL.jpg)
this pic shown, when I clicked the enter button, the localhost/ex2/here.php or the name of your php file will permanently load unless you click the **X** button on the cmd of sendmail.exe..

When I clicked the **X** button on the cmd of sendmail.exe, this message will shown on my php file [img Problem #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIK1D.jpg)

And this is my code in sending email from gmail:

```
  <?php

$message = "This message will directly POSTED to your GMAIL account";
$headers = "From: rence.samboy@gmail.com";

if(mail('rence.samboy@gmail.com', 'Example', $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Text message is sent to rence.samboy@gmail.com.....<BR/>";
}
else
{
echo "Not Work..";
}
?>
```

`**Much appreciate if you can help me to fix my problem**` :)

Comment: In bigger picture, what do you wish to achieve here? Is it a personal hobby project, or paid project/work? This is because using the build in `mail` to send emails is the worst choice of all to be frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... for sending email, you need to set your gmail configuration first, such as protocol, smtp port, etc.

For me... I'm using CodeIgnitor framework and this code that I've added in my controller:

```
public function send_mail() { 

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465, //or 587
        'smtp_timeout' => 7,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', //your gmail account
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', //your gmail password
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE,
        'newline' => "\r\n"
    );

        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        $shipment_code = $_POST["shipment_code"];
        $array = "Phone No: ".$phone."<br>Email: ".$email."<br>Shipment Code: ".$shipment_code."<br>Message: ".$message;

         //Load email library 
         $this->load->library('email', $config); 

         $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com');
         $this->email->to('xxx@xxx.com');
         $this->email->cc($email);
         $this->email->subject($subject); 
         $this->email->message($array); 

         //Send mail 
         if($this->email->send()) 
         $this->session->set_flashdata('email_sent',"<h2>Your email was sent successfully.</h2>");
         else 
         $this->session->set_flashdata('email_sent',"Error in sending Email."); 
         echo $this->email->print_debugger();
         $this->load->view('views_contactus');

}
```

If you want to see the view, then visit [this](https://anakpanti.com/ab-cargo/controllers_contactus/).

Answer (score 0):

php.ini

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = YOUR_MAIL@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=YOUR_MAIL@gmail.com
auth_password=YOUR_MAIL_PASS
force_sender=YOUR_MAIL@gmail.com
```

php.ini
   extension=php_openssl.dll